# Visual Studio 2013 Ultimate Error while trying to debug an mvc application

Tags: asp.net-mvc, visual-studio, debugging, visual-studio-2013

I am developing a MVC web application.  I had an issue where VS 2013 sp3 ultimate was not launching anymore so I uninstalled and re-installed VS 2013 sp4 ultimate.  I am able to launch my web application using Start Without Debugging. However, when I try to debug my application I get a Microsoft Visual Studio pop-up error message that says:

> Uncaught exception thrown by method called through Reflection.

It's not even reaching my application I am unable to even debug where this message is coming from.

I've already tried enabling 'Native Code' on all the included projects in my solution.

Comment: This issue can be caused by Visual Studio not installed properly, did you try to re-install?

Comment: I did re-install 2x and I repair 3x finally on the 4th repair the issue was resolved.  Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

After several attempts to repair the final attempt solved the problem. Thank you.